# Angular 8 Datatable Date Sorting Issue dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatable, angular8

I am not able to sorting date in ascending order in Angular Datatable. Please help.The date format i am getting from api is yyyy-mm-dd and i had converted it to dd-mm-yyyy using render function.

Since I want to show date only in dd-mm-yyyy in datatable ,I am converting it.

Please check the image for reference (First Row and last row)

**HTML Class**

```
   <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger"  class="row-border hover">
   </table>
```

In Components Class I have used dtoptions for displaying the data

```
this.dtOptions = {

  ajax: {
    url: environment.api_base_url + "abc",

    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      "abccreateddate": this.myDate,

    },
    dataSrc: function (json) {
      //alert(json);
      let return_array = [];
      return_array = json;
      return return_array;
    }

  },
  "order": [[2, "asc"]],
  'columnDefs': [ { 'type': 'date', 'targets': 2 } ],
  columns: [

    {
      title: 'ReportName',
      data: 'reportname',

    },
    {
      title: 'Report Start Date',
      data: 'reportstartdate',
      "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return  ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +"-"+ (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    }
    },
    {
      title: 'Report Due Date',
      data: 'reportduedate',
      "render": function (data) {
        var date = new Date(data);
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        return  ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) +"-"+ (month.toString().length > 1 ? month : "0" + month) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    }
  }
```

]

My response from API:

[{"reportname":"TestReport1","reportstartdate":"2020-04-30","reportduedate":"2020-04-30"},
{"reportname":"Monthlynew","reportstartdate":"2020-03-28","reportduedate":"2020-04-04"}
]

[please check pic for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxyXD.png)

Comment: There's no code there that sorts anything, and without seeing the data you want to sort, the answer is a pineapple - oh, wait is `"order": [[2, "asc"]],` supposed to sort by column 2 which is described as type 'date'?

Comment: Hi Jaromanda,I have added the json response

Comment: how does the property names `reportstartdate` and `reportduedate` relate to the `columns:[]`? the columns appear to be `reportname`, `creationdate` and `lastdate` - but the data has `reportname`, `reportstartdate` and `reportduedate`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have edited it

Comment: right, now it looks more believable ... what happens if you remove the `columnDefs` property - it'd be interesting because dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` order can be sorted using simple alpha sort

Comment: Yes yyyy-mm-dd is sorting perfectly, but I want the date in dd-mm-yyyy(requirement) , show it in ascending order.

Comment: so, because you render using dd-mm-yyyy, it now sorts using dd-mm-yyyy (if you remove columnDefs that is)? so `order` is done after `render`? - lets face it, the image shows it isn't sorting in any way

Answer (score 0):

try the following for the `render` method

```
render: function ( data, type) {

    var dateDisplay = data.split('-').reverse().join('-');
    return type === "display" || type === "filter" ? dateDisplay : data;
}
```

based on: [datatables manual for render function](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) see "Transforming data"

As a bonus, I've included an easier way to change yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy